# RTK Query: How to access POST mutation response from other component? Is it cached like a GET request, if so how to access?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

Can I access POST mutation response from another component?  That is, is it cached like a Query/GET request?

1. API with POST/mutation `createTest` to server:

   Of note, I do not have a GET request endpoint to GET Tests, unfortunately.

   ```js
   export const testApi = createApi({
     reducerPath: 'testApi',
     baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: TEST_API_BASE_PATH }),
     tagTypes: ['Test'],
     endpoints: (builder) => ({
       createTest: builder.mutation<
         CreateTestResponse,
         CreateTestRequest
       >({
         query: (payload) => ({
           url: '',
           method: 'POST',
           body: payload,
         }),
         invalidatesTags: ['Test'],
       }),
     }),
   });

   export const { useCreateTestMutation } = testApi;
   ```
2. Payload is an object retrieved from a form component.
3. POST returns a response.

   For example:

   ```
   {
       data: {
           firstName: "Bluey",
           lastName: "Heeler"
       }
   }
   ```
4. I call `createTest` in a component like this:

   ```
   const SomeComponent = ({ payload }) => {
       const [createTest] = useCreateTestMutation();

       const someCallback = useCallback(() => {
           try {
               const testResult = createTest(payload);

               // do stuff with Test Result

           } catch (err) {
               // do stuff with error
           }
       }, [...]);


       return (
           <div>
               ...
               <Button onClick={someCallback} />
               ....
           </div>
       )
   }
   ```
5. I would like to get the result/response of that mutation in another component, similar to the cached response from a GET request/useQuery.  Do you know how?
6. I have resorted to creating an RTK Slice and setting the response there in global state.  I get the feeling that that is not the "correct" way of using RTK Query, however.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [explicitly set a cache key](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations#shared-mutation-results) if you want to share mutation results.

```js
export const ComponentOne = () => {
  // Triggering `updatePostOne` will affect the result in both this component,
  // but as well as the result in `ComponentTwo`, and vice-versa
  const [updatePost, result] = useUpdatePostMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'shared-update-post',
  })

  return <div>...</div>
}

export const ComponentTwo = () => {
  const [updatePost, result] = useUpdatePostMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'shared-update-post',
  })

  return <div>...</div>
}
```

Comment: Heh, so my answer wasn't incorrect, it was just incomplete. 

Comment: Nice.  That is super helpful. Thank you!